# How to create words of random letters?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, hashset, treeset

This is the instructions of my assigment:

"Construct a program that lets the user create different words from random letters consequences. 
The words must be checked against a dictionary."

This is the code so far:

```
import java.util.Arrays;



public class AngloTrainer {
// ...

public AngloTrainer(String dictionaryFile) throws IOException {
    // load dictionary?
    //what else?
}

private String sort(String s){

    //Sort the letters in a string. 
    char[] tecken = s.toCharArray();
    String sorted = Arrays.sort(tecken);
    return sorted;

}

// use this to verify loadDictionary
private void dumpDict() {
    // Print out the dictionary at the screen.
      // ... define!
}

private void loadDictionary( String fileName ) {
    // Read the dictionary into a suitable container.
    // The file is a simple text file. One word per line.
    FileReader flr = new Filereader(fileName);  
    BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(flr);
    String line;
    //collection/treeset?? maybe other??
    while((line = bfr.readLine()) !=null ){
        //save to a collention, but which?
    }
}

private String randomLetters( int length ) {
    // this makes vovels a little more likely
    String letters = "aabcdeefghiijklmnoopqrstuuvwxyyz";  
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(length);
    for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ ) 
        buf.append( letters.charAt(randomGenerator.nextInt(letters.length())));

    return buf.toString();
}


/* Def. includes    
 * Let #(x,s) = the number of occurrences of the charcter x in the string s.
 * includes(a,b) holds iff for every character x in b, #(x,b) <= #(x,a)
 * 
 * A neccessary precondition for includes is that both strings are sorted
 * in ascending order.
 */
private boolean includes( String a, String b ) {
    if ( b == null || b.length() == 0 )
        return true;
    else if ( a == null || a.length() == 0 )
        return false;

    //precondition: a.length() > 0 && b.length() > 0
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while ( j < b.length() ) {
        if (i >= a.length() || b.charAt(j) < a.charAt(i))
            return false;
        else if (b.charAt(j) == a.charAt(i)) {
            i++; j++;
        } else if (b.charAt(j) > a.charAt(i))
            i++;
    }
    //postcondition: j == b.length()
    return true;
}




public static void main(String[] args) {
    // ... define!
}
}
```

Which collection should I use for the loadDictionary method?
As the assignment said, i need to check words i type against the dictionary collection.

Comment: I suggest you to construct a trie in which the look ups are efficient!

Comment: What collections have you tried? What happened when you tried them?

Comment: You have tagged the question `hashset` and `treeset`.  Have you tried either of those?

Answer (score 0):

A [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) offers better average case theoretic complexity - however, note that `HashSet` is by definition unordered. That means that there is no correlation between 'realated' words (for example, `cat` and `catfish` could be placed very distant from each other).

`Hashset` offers `O(1)` (or `O(|S|)` to be exact since you do need to read the string) look-up and insertion.

A [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) is theoretically slower than `HashSet`, and has `O(logN)` (or again, `O(|S|logn)` since the string still needs to be read).

However, `TreeSet` is an instance of [`SortedSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html). That means that words that are 'close' to each other according to the Comparator used, are also going to be placed close to each other in it. In the default implementation of [`String.compareTo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) - the ordering used is [lexicographic order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). That means that words which share the same prefix will be 'close' to each other. So, if you later on intend to extend your implementation to allowing words completion for example - a `TreeSet` is a better choice, as you can use the [`tailSet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#tailSet%28E%29) method for it.

TreeSet also does not suffer from worst case complexity of `O(n)`, so if [latency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latency_%28engineering%29) is an issue in your system - they should be prefered over `HashSet`s that needs `O(n)` operations once in a while to maintain the data structure.

In addition, you can use an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) - and make sure you sort it with [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html). It should do the trick since your dictionary is static, while the `Set`s are more focused on dynamic (constantly changing dictionaries). You can later find if a word is in the list using [`Collections.binarySearch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T%29)

Other data structures that are optimized for strings are [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), [Radix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) (a more space efficient variant of trie). However - those are not implemented in the built in java Collections library. If you later on finds performance an issue, and in need for a speed up for this specific part of your code - you should consider switching to a non-built in data structure, but as starter - get things working, don't prematurely optimize it.